# Pass an exception thrown inside a Helper.java listener to Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, exception, firebase-realtime-database

I Have this huge method that the only purpose is to update firebase email. The only problem I'm having here is not firebase related, but since I don't want to put all this code on my activity (And, of course, I want to **call this method from wherever user is**) how can I **Handle trown exceptions from my activity** so I can show to user if his email was not updated because it's worng formated or because his password was typed wrong?

**Helper.java**

```java
public static void updateEmailProfile(final User user, final String newEmail) {
// getAuth credentials from user for re-authentication
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
        .getCredential(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()); // current login credentials

final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
firebaseUser.reauthenticate(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    // here is safe to update email[
                    firebaseUser.updateEmail(newEmail)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                               
                                Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated");
                            }
                            else {
                                try {
                                    throw (task.getException());
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // wrong email format
                                    Log.d(TAG, "updateEmailProfile - updateEmail" + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    try {
                        throw (task.getException());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // wrong password typed
                        Log.d(TAG, "updateEmailProfile: - reauthenticate: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

As shown, exceptions are thrown inside listeners, what makes it harder to return it.

This is how i'm trying to treat error on my activity, but (of course) it's not catching exception

**MainActivity.java**

```java
try {
    if (input.getText() != null) {
        user.setPassword(input.getText().toString());
        Helper.updateEmailProfile(user, newEmail); // here i'm calling previous method
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "email updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "password not filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "error to update email" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Is there a way that I can throw this exceptions from Helper.java method to my activity, so there, I can show it to user?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the method `updateEmailProfile` throw an exception. By doing this, your activity can catch the exception.

To do so, you could change the updateEmailProfile signature to something like:

```java
updateEmailProfile(final User user, final String newEmail) throws Exception {

....

}
```

You also need to remove the `try/catches` inside the updateEmailProfile(), so that the method dispatch the exception to the `try/catch` block that's calling it, which is in MainActivity.

Comment: Interesting. But when I call ```throw (task.getException());``` I'm forced to catch this exception. Is there a way that I can bypass that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface which calls your method and returns it's success or failure.

On your activity:

```
private val callBack: OnCallBack = object : OnCallBack {
        override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
           your failure
        }

        override fun onResponse(response: Response?, type: Int) {
           your success
        }
}
```

Your Interface:

```
interface OnCallBack {
    fun onResponse(response: Response?)
    fun onError(t: Throwable?)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better how can I implement this on my case. It's not clear for me. Thanks!

Comment: You have a methedo which calls your firebase implementation, right? And it has it's own onSuccess and onFailure responses.

You will create an object of the type of the interface and call each of the interface's methods on the firebase corresponding response. Then you will implement the same interface on yout activity. Every time your method calls the interface, it will call the interface's methods on your activity and, thus, pass your success or error.